# Android/Java: Class not loaded

Tags: java, android, class, debugging, object

I have been bugging some code and noticed that for some reason now I am getting this object error

> com.result.mobile.ui.R.drawable.outwards = Class not loaded :
>   com.result.mobile.ui.R

Sometimes if I leave the debugger at this point it will suddenly load and initialise the object however the majority of the time it doesn't.

What useful suggestions would help me resolve this issue?

I have tried simply rebuilding the project and restarting intelliJ but none work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try cleaning the project. Always worth a shot.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I'm still having the same issue :S

Comment: On another object it was also not loading the class for and it was originally was just set to 'private static' and I added the 'final' modifier as it made sense to and it now doesn't give me any issues so I think this has resolved it, seem's strange though.

Comment: Cleaning and rebuilding the project helped indeed! Thanks.